# How to remove a line with matching string but not start with # in a file?

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script to remove certain line with pattern in a file.
The file contains lot of similar pattern like these and want to remove only line begin with 'export ROS_' but not with '#' at first.

```
#export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.34:11311
#export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.34

export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.33:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.33
```

Comment: consider reviewing [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update your question accordingly; in particular, provide the code you've tried, the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) desired output

Comment: `printf "%s\n" "g/^export ROS_/d" w | ed -s file`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sed` tool:

```
sed "/^export ROS_/d" file
```

or with a bash-only syntax:

```
while read line; do
  case "$line" in
    "export ROS_"*) ;;
    *) echo "$line" ;;
  esac
done < file
```

Even simpler:

```
while read line; do
    [[ "$line" =~ ^"export ROS_" ]] || echo "$line"
done < file
```

Comment: Only this works 
input="bashrc"
sed -i '/^export ROS_/d' "$input"

Other solution didn't actually removed the line that begin with "export ROS_"

Comment: Didn't get that you asked for an in place file editing. The other solutions just output the filtered lines to stdout and thus require to redirect this output to another text file with the operand `>`.